# Best way to compare JSON array with another JSON array with Regex Values?

Tags: java, json, regex, validation, hashmap

I have to validate the values of output json file. First validation is all the key value pairs needed are in the file and the second one, values are in the correct format as expected ( say, timestamp, string, integer ...). I cannot compare the values directly with another file having same content as some of the values like timestamp, id are random.

JSON File:

```
[
  {
    "metadata": {
      "RecordEnd": 19,
      "Type": null,
      "RecordOffset": 0,
      "Character_Set": "UTF-8",
      "MsgType": 8,
      "Expire": 0,
      "Name": "y1",
      "delivered": false,
      "Timestamp": 1664189426609,
      "UserID": "1jnj2232",
      "Encoding": 273,
      "id": "ID:414d51205120202020210040",
      "DType": "type1"
    }
]
```

I have two approches to do this.

1. Create a hashmap with keys as same in the JSON file and have values as regex patterns and compare each key value pairs with the regex matching the keys.

```
HashMap<String,String> metaData = new HashMap();
metaData.put("RecordEnd","\\d+");metaData.put("Type","\\w+");
metaData.put("RecordOffset","\\d+");metaData.put("Character_Set","UTF-8");
metaData.put("MsgType","\\d+");metaData.put("Expire","\\w+");
metaData.put("Name","\\w+");metaData.put("delivered","\\w+");
metaData.put("Timestamp","\\d+");metaData.put("UserID","\\w+");
metaData.put("Encoding","\\d+");metaData.put("id","ID\\:\\w+");
metaData.put("DType","type1");


ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(outputJSONFile),"UTF-8");
json = json.substring(1, json.length() - 1);
Map<?, ?> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);

HashMap<String,Object> metaMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) map.get("metadata");
metaMap.entrySet().forEach(e-> {
  if (!(e.getValue() == null)) {
    if (e.getValue().toString().matches(metaData.get(e.getKey()))) {
      log.info(e + "- Matched");
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(
          "MetaData key " + e.getKey() + " data is invalid");
    }
  }
});
```

Here, if the fields size become larger ( say 40+ fields) , I have to add hashmap values for all the fields , it becomes a tedious process and reduces readability.

2. Create a static json file with the all the keys and the values in the regex format. Then, compare the two files based on regex of one file to match with another file. I haven't tried this yet.

Is the second approach more efficient or is there a more suitable approach to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using JSON Schema?

Comment: @Rubydesic I have no idea what a JSON Schema is . Could you kindly explain me how it will be useful to me in this case or direct to any resource regarding JSON Schema

Comment: @Rubydesic I looked into JSON Schema. It is not suitable for my problem, as I need a library to use the validation in my java code and importantly, I cannot define the values of fields as certain format which can give me a more proper validation

Comment: JSON Schema can do [regex validation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html) as you are doing, although you can replace most of your validations with required types (i.e.` \\d+` is really just validating that the field is an [`integer`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#integer)). And there are libraries that implement JSON schema validation in Java, such as [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator).

Comment: @Rubydesic As for now, I have done the validation by creating a java properties file to have the fields and create a hash-map from the properties. JSON Schema seems cool, but I have a constraint of not including any new library into the project. Thanks for the JSON Schema 